# Running Ruby build code via Sublime's Command Line

Tags: ruby, build, sublimetext2

Is it possible to enter your ruby code in sublime, then run build, open the command line in sublime and actually execute the code that was just built? I'm reading conflicting things on if this is how it's suppose to work or not. Found an older thread from July on here that asked the same question but it seemed that person just wanted to know why his `puts` wasn't being ran when he ran "build".

To give a better example of what I was wondering you can do in Sublime is if I wrote this in sublime

```
class BookInStock
    def initialize(isbn, price)
        @isbn = isbn
        @price = Float(price)
    end
    def to_S
        "ISBN: #{@isbn}, price: #{@price}"
    end
end
```

Then I saved it, and ran build. Then opened up Sublime's command line and typed in `book = BookInStore.new("what","ever)` then ran `puts book` and having it spit back something.

I'm hoping this is possible. I mean typing stuff out then saving it then switching over to terminal to run it isn't bad, just would love to be able to do this from Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. However, it will require a plugin installed for Sublime Text. This plugin is called [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL). I've been using it for quite some time now, and it accomplishes what you are trying to achieve.

Once you install the plugin (check the page I linked to for instructions), you can run your code in a ruby interpreter within Sublime Text by doing the following:

1. Launch the plugin with "Ctrl+shift+p" and search "SublimeRepl: ruby". Hit enter.
2. Open the tab with the ruby code you would like to use within the interpreter
3. Press "Ctrl+[comma], f" --- (ctrl plus a comma, and then the f key)
4. Navigate back to the tab that opened when you launched the plugin, and you should now be able to create instances of your class within the interpreter.

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks for this, exactly what I was looking for! After installing this package I've found that apparently my $PATH (OSX) is messed up due to some sudo installs I did when I first set up my mac. Now I'm descending into madness trying to correct all the mistakes.

Comment: Which error are you getting? I know when I first started running this plugin, I had to do a little manual intervention myself.